# How to get name of an input field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, input

Creating a plugin in jQuery, I have to get the names of input fields on which events would occur.

Suppose:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="age" />
```

Whether submitted or not doesn't matter. What I want is to get the name of the field.

I tried the following:

```
$('#ins').html($(this).attr('name').val());
```

`#ins` is the div, where I am writing the events such as a `click` was made on the input with `name = name`. This way I want to create a plugin which would guide me to get to know which fields are getting some events.

Comment: `$(this).attr('name')` is enough

Comment: Could you post the whole of your plugin? Without context it's hard to offer a valid suggestion.

Comment: @Peter has provided the perfect and in time answer :) It was the `val()` thing messing up! Now its perfect :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are bit right but when you trying to access attribute you have to use only the `attr` not the `val()`.

```
$(this).attr('name')
```

The above code is enough to get the name of the event triggered elements name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function(){
   $('#ins').html($(this).attr('name') + " <br>");
});
```

with this code, you will get the name  attribute of all input in the page.
And i put a "br" just to break a line.

Comment: its fair now, and just as i wanted! :D I wanted the `<br />` too :)

Comment: its difficult in case of dimensional field name